# AuthBot integration with Cortana for Bot Framework

Tags: c#, authentication, azure-active-directory, botframework

Is there a way to integrate [Authbot](https://github.com/MicrosoftDX/AuthBot) with cortana channel to enable user authentication in bot framework? 
I seem to find no solution for it. I can't switch to using normal authentication using email as shown in cortana docs, as my other channels are using Authbot.